# angular4 rxjs Observable reduce returns type different then original passed in

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

angular4 typescript rxjs 5

I have complex type passed in reduce method but i want return type to be different boolean .

Rite now with following code i am getting return type error not match

```
Observable.from(myList).reduce((complex1, complex2) => {
return complex1.flag && complex2.flag; // gives me error
})
```

Comment: from takes a map function, but this might be something done on the subscribing side of the observable? otherwise you can reduce it before putting it into an observable.

Comment: Or maybe reduce is not what you want but rather .map()?

Comment: You've not provided a seed, so the accumulator will be initialized with the first element. Which means its type will be the element type. However, you are returning the result of a boolean expression - not an element.

Comment: thanks cartant your comment solves my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing that `myList` is `Array<{ flag: bool }>` and you want to check if all flags are true, you probably want:

```
Observable.from(myList)
          .reduce((accumulated, complex) => accumulated && complex.flag, true);
```

Your reducing function is responsible for combining the previous iteration value (or second argument, initially) with the newly-emitted value from your `Observable`, in order to reduce your stream to a scalar value. This way, your reducing function has the same return type *and* first-argument type as the final value.